# Jquery Datepicket Daterange - Select date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I set datepicket of jquery to start from 1965 to some years as shown below. But when I select date then it sets date of current 2012 year.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dateinput').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1965:' + ((new Date).getFullYear() - 12) + ''
    });
});
```

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nnnn:-nn` format as well.

So try `1965:-12`

Edit: Your code seems to work in the latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/gTszs/

Comment: not working.. I tried above code.. It sets current year with default date 2012. How can I change it to 1965 as calender default month.

Comment: Does it work correctly in the link I posted? If not, please tell me what browser you're using.

Comment: No, in you link it selects as 2012 year. It should select start year from 1965

Comment: Its not working in jsfiddle link given. It selects 2012 year.

Comment: I am using latest chrome and firefox tested in both browser.

Comment: It is done with setting default date.

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dateinput').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1965:' + ((new Date).getFullYear() - 12) + '',
            defaultDate: new Date(1965, 1, 1)
        });
    });

http://jsfiddle.net/gTszs/1/